# Awk/Bash writing script

Tags: bash, awk, self

I want to write a code that will output an awk and bash script.  This script basically cuts a file up into small pieces for programs to run in parallel and I want to control the number of peices, rather then having a set number as I do now.  My current code is set to cut the file into 10 parts using awk and then execute a bash script.

```
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10)&&NR>=0) print }' $1 > $11
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10*2)&&NR>=(a/10*1)) print }' $1 >$12
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10*3)&&NR>=(a/10*2)) print }' $1 >$13
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10*4)&&NR>=(a/10*3)) print }' $1 >$14
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10*5)&&NR>=(a/10*4)) print }' $1 >$15
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10*6)&&NR>=(a/10*5)) print }' $1 >$16
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10*7)&&NR>=(a/10*6)) print }' $1 >$17
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10*8)&&NR>=(a/10*7)) print }' $1 >$18
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<(a/10*9)&&NR>=(a/10*8)) print }' $1 >$19
awk -v a=$a '{if (NR<=(a/10*10)&&NR>=(a/10*9)) print }' $1 >$110

bash $2 $11&
bash $2 $12&
bash $2 $13&
bash $2 $14&
bash $2 $15&
bash $2 $16&
bash $2 $17&
bash $2 $18&
bash $2 $19&
bash $2 $110&
```

I want it so I can type in 20 and it will write this script out 20 times.  I just can't seem to come up with a way to do this with a loop in my head.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT

Some more information on variables

```
a=`wc -l $1 | cut -f 1 -d " "`
```

I'm also not sure how to write a loop to give the following code:

```
cat $11.tab $12.tab $13.tab $14.tab $15.tab $16.tab $17.tab $18.tab $19.tab $110.tab > $3
```

Comment: You should have a look at the `split` command, which can replace your series of awk commands (and would only have to scan the file once).  Then you could just loop through the set of files produced by `split` and fire off your parallel bash commands.

Comment: `$110` is presumably a typo for `$20`, which should be `${20}`. All double digit positional parameters should be enclosed in braces — [positional parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters).  If you mean `${1}1`, `${1}2`, etc, then you should use the brace to make that clear (or use a dot to separate the parts `$1.1`, or ...).

Comment: What is the value in `$a`?  Is it the number of lines in `$1`?  As in `a=$(wc -l < $1)` or therabouts?

Comment: see edits... split is a nice program to know about.  Would have saved me several lines in this program.

Comment: Can I use cat *  to concatenate all the files at the end (if I put them in a single folder) since it runs in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't explore alternatives like using `split` or `csplit` to partition the file.

Assuming that `a=$(wc -l < $1)`, and that `$3` contains the number of fragments (10 in the example written out longhand), then you can take your existing code and package it as one or two loops using `seq` to generate the numbers you need:

```
a=$(wc -l < "$1")
n=${3:-10}
for i in $(seq 1 $n)
do
    # a = number of records in file
    # n = number of parts the file is to be split into
    # p = part number of current part
    awk -v a=$a -v n=$n -v p=$i '{if (NR<(a/n*p)&&NR>=(a/n*(p-1))) print }' "$1" >"$1.$i"
    bash "$2" "$1.$i" &
done
wait   # For all the background processes to complete
```

That's the single loop version; you can create all the files first and then run a second loop to create all the background processes.

I strongly suspect that you could use a single `awk` script to split the file:

```
a=$(wc -l < "$1")
n=${3:-10}
awk -v a=$a -v n=$n -v f="$1" -e \
   '{   nfn = int((n*NR)/a)+1;
        if (nfn != ofn)
        {
            ofile = sprintf("%s.%d", f, nfn);
            ofn = nfn;
        }
        print > ofile
    }' "$1"

for i in $(seq 1 $3)
do
    bash "$2" "$1.$i" &
done
wait   # For all the background processes to complete
```

None of this code has been past `awk` or `bash` so there could be mistakes in it.

Comment: would you mind explaining the n= statement, I don't understand it.

Comment: You can pass shell variables to `awk` as `awk` variables using `-v var=value` notation.  Thus, I've passed three shell variables to the second `awk` script: `$a` to be called `a` in the `awk` script, and `$n` to be called `n`, and `"$1"` to be called `f`.  I could have used `-v lines=$a` to name a variable `lines` in `awk` from the shell variable `$a`; there is no obligation to use the same name in shell and `awk` (but it often makes sense to do so).

Comment: sorry I meant the n=${3:-10} statement

Comment: Ah: [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  `n=${3:-10}` means 'set `n` to the value of `$3` unless `$3` is unset or empty, in which case use the default value of 10'.

Answer (score 1):

`split` looks like a simpler alternative:

```
INPUT=$1  # input file
N=$2      # number of lines per file
SCRIPT=$3 # script to run

mkdir chunks
cd chunks
split "../$INPUT" -l "$N"
for file in *; do
   bash "../$SCRIPT" "$file" &
done
```